# Is setters and getters are coding standards in java or We can write our wish?

Tags: java

Below Code with Setters and Getters:

```
public class DemoApp {
private int value;

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoApp demoApp = new DemoApp();
    demoApp.setValue(10);
    System.out.println("value is" + demoApp.getValue());
}
}
```

Below Code Is My own Code here I changed set to put and get to take While changing like this, is not a problem or it will give any future problem to me.

```
public class DemoApp {

private int value;

public int takeValue() {
    return value;
}

public void putValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoApp demoApp = new DemoApp();
    demoApp.putValue(10);
    System.out.println("value is" + demoApp.takeValue());
}
}
```

Comment: They are supposed to follow java bean spec as a best practice

Answer (score 2):

Your class will be unusable in any context that requires conformance to the Java Beans Specification, which includes most if not all Web frameworks and many others.

Don't be different just for the sake of it. 'Take' is a particularly poor choice, as it already has another meaning with queues. Ditto 'put' and maps.

Comment: Not only "take" If we put any name instated of set and get it will execute properly.

Comment: @Prabha, In your case it works, but at Java Framework like `Spring Framework`, it will  not work.

Comment: @Prabha Your comment is pointless, and already contradicted by my first sentence. I don't think you've understood one word of this answer.

Comment: In any framework in place of getX we can use any name but setX we can't use other names it should be same like setX only.if we use different name we will get null value.

Comment: @Prabha That is not correct. You must use `is,` `get,` and `set` in any framework that requires conformance to the Java Beans Specification, by definition.

Comment: @EJP I did example using struts and hibernate framework in place of get I used another name and it executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The convention, as established by the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html), is to use `setV`, `getV`; however, your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can give any name to the method you wish for. But generally its the coding convention that is followed. So **its always preferred that you give relevant name** for getter and setter for the member fields of your class.

Answer (score 0):

get and set are conventions widely used as names for that purpose. So when other developer uses your code and needs getter he will instantly try to find get method. Your other code variant will work without problems, but other developers reading your code will bi a little confused.

Anyway, best practice is to just stick to conventions.

Comment: Can I make My put and take like set and get By default? I mean get and set generate internally like that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can always write code as you wish, provided only you are going to maintain it for whole life of that code either or you make it much clear to understand for people who are going to maintain that(and obviously it has to fulfill business requirements :))!!

Comment: Thank you very much... Can I make My put and take like set and get By default? I mean get and set generate internally like that ?

Comment: @Prabha How do you mean "generate internally"? If you use IDE (like eclipse) there is a option to generate getter and setter methods automatically. It is nothing special, it just writes method instead of you.

Answer (score 0):

Getter and setter methods are used for accessing the variable. If you use public variable wherever it can be changed without setters.

The coding convention is also one of the reason to create getter and setter.